# Symfony2 - Use a third party library (SSRS)

Tags: php, symfony, reporting-services

Maybe dumb question, I'm new to Symfony2 and I'm using it for one of my projects.
I'd like to be able to use a third party library, namely [SSRSReport](http://ssrsphp.codeplex.com/) (an API for SSRS Reports).

I have put the library into `Symfony/vendor/ssrs/lib/Ssrs/src`.
There are many classes defined here, I don't need them to be autoloaded.

I simply don't know how to require and call them from a controller.

For sure this doesn't work

```
require_once '/vendor/ssrs/lib/Ssrs/src/SSRSReport.php';
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function viewAction()
    {
        define("UID", "xxxxxxxx");
        define("PASWD", "xxxxxxxx");
        define("SERVICE_URL", "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ReportServer/");
        $report = new SSRSReport(new Credentials(UID, PASWD), SERVICE_URL);
        return $this->render('myBundle:Default:view.html.twig'
            , array('report' => $report)
        );
    }
}
```

`SSRSReport()` and `Credentials()` used here, are 2 of many classes contained into the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I don't recommend putting non-symfony-managed libraries into `/vendors`.  Since you're managing this library, put it into `/src`.

Secondly, when using classes that aren't namespace (i.e., are in the root namespace), make sure you reference them properly or else PHP will look in the current namespace (which, in this case, is your controller namespace)

Thirdly, the quick-and-dirty solution is to just properly include the files from the controller:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    protected function includeSsrsSdk()
    {
      require_once(
          $this->container->getParameter( 'kernel.root_dir' )
        . '/../src/ssrs/lib/Ssrs/src/SSRSReport.php'
      );
    }

    public function viewAction()
    {
        $this->includeSsrsSdk();
        define("UID", "xxxxxxxx");
        define("PASWD", "xxxxxxxx");
        define("SERVICE_URL", "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ReportServer/");
        $report = new \SSRSReport(new \Credentials(UID, PASWD), SERVICE_URL);
        return $this->render('myBundle:Default:view.html.twig'
            , array('report' => $report)
        );
    }
}
```

But that locks your logic for including the library into this one controller.  You could make a separate wrapper for the SDK that does this, or even register it as a service.

Comment: Hi @Peter Bailey, thanks for your answer but could you explain how to define a third party library as a service which is a cleaner solution ? And Would it be possible to register a third party as a service even if there are no classes defined but just some functions and requires .. ?

Comment: I personally simply instantiated the API from a new service

Comment: could you please check if you can help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259178/uncaught-soapfault-exception-wsdl-soap-error-parsing-wsdl

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using composer with symfony, so this is my suggestion.

Instead of require_once, you should use composer's autoload mechanism for autoloading non namespaced libraries or functions http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files

So just update the autoload section in composer.json.

```
   "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" },
        "files": ["src/SsrsReport/SSRSReport.php"]
   },
```

For consuming the service I would either use a Facade (extends SSRSREport class) or a Factory which returns it.