# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL

Tags: php, soap, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm using [SSRS SDK for PHP](https://ssrsphp.codeplex.com/)

PHP Version 5.4

WebServer: Centos 6.4

MSSQL Server 2008 R2

When I make

```
$ssrs_report = new SSRSReport(new Credentials(UID, PASWD), SERVICE_URL);
```

I got the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: 
Couldn't load from 'http://172.16.4.63/ReportServerURL/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fTestFolder%2ftestClaimHdr&rs:Command=Render/ReportExecution2005.asmx?wsdl' : 
Premature end of data in tag html line 1 in /var/www/emilio/app/Libraries/SSRSReport/bin/SSRSReport.php:196 

Stack trace: #0 /var/www/emilio/app/Libraries/SSRSReport/bin/SSRSReport.php(196): 
SoapClient->SoapClient('http://172.16.4...', Array) #1 /var/www/emilio/SSRS/index.php(12): 
SSRSReport->SSRSReport(Object(Credentials), 'http://172.16.4...') #2 {main} thrown in 
/var/www/emilio/app/Libraries/SSRSReport/bin/SSRSReport.php on line 196
```

**I'm looking how to fix it and get the report trough the soap([SSRS SDK for PHP](https://ssrsphp.codeplex.com/)).**

I tried using `file_get_content()` and `curl` and both worked fine, then isn't connection problems, I have

- Soap Client  enabled
- allow_url_fopen is On

this is the line where the sdk call the soap service

```
$executionServiceUrl="http://172.16.4.63/ReportServerURL?%2fTestFolder%2ftestClaimHdr&rs:Command=Render/ReportExecution2005.asmx?wsdl";
$options = array ( 'login' => 'xxxx\\xxxx', 'password' => 'xxxx', )

$this->_soapHandle_Exe = new SoapClient($executionServiceUrl, $options);
```

Adding

```
 try {
  $this->_soapHandle_Exe = new SoapClient($executionServiceUrl, $options);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  var_export(libxml_get_last_error());
}
```

I get the following array:

```
LibXMLError::__set_state(array(
      'level' => 3,
      'code' => 77,
      'column' => 43325,
      'message' => 'Premature end of data in tag html line 1',
      'file' => 'http://172.16.4.63/ReportServerURL?%2fTestFolder%2ftestClaimHdr&rs:Command=Render/ReportExecution2005.asmx?WSDL',
      'line' => 1,
)
```

According to [xmlerror from libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlerror.html)

> level 3 = XML_ERR_FATAL = 3 : A fatal error
>
> code 77 =  XML_ERR_TAG_NOT_FINISHED = 77 : 77

I have alredy set the [Basic authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281309%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in the SSRS SERVER

**Update**

As @jwhaley58 said I changed to:

```
define("SERVICE_URL", "http://172.16.4.63/ReportServerURL");
$ssrs_report = new SSRSReport(new Credentials(UID, PASWD), SERVICE_URL);
$ssrs_report->LoadReport2('testClaimHdr',NULL);
```

and I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SSRSReportException' in 
/var/www/emilio/app/Libraries/SSRSReport/bin/SSRSReport.php:590 Stack trace: #0 
/var/www/emilio/app/Libraries/SSRSReport/bin/SSRSReport.php(326): 
SSRSReport->ThrowReportException(Object(SoapFault)) #1 /var/www/emilio/SSRS/index.php(15): 
SSRSReport->LoadReport2('testClaimHdr', NULL) #2 {main} thrown in 
/var/www/emilio/app/Libraries/SSRSReport/bin/SSRSReport.php on line 590
```

Comment: You might try pointing it to the ReportService2010 endpoint instead of the 2005 one?

Comment: @kyzen I tried with 2010, the same result, using the url `http://172.16.4.63/ReportServerURL?%2fTestFolder%2ftestClaimHdr&rs:Command=Render/ReportExecution2005.asmx?wsdl` in the browser, with `file_get_content` and `curl` works fine with 2005

Comment: I'm going to check back on this later tonight - I had these same problems about a year ago, and managed to get it working somehow.  If I still have the code lying around I'll come back and post what I had to do to get it working with SSRS 2012.

Comment: I'm looking through the code you provided, I may be reading it wrong, but it looks like you are trying to explicitly define the report you're after in the execution url. If that is in fact what you are doing, I believe the fix would be to only define the report base you are connecting to so for your example the url should be `http://172.16.4.63/ReportServer/`. After that connection is made, you would use the LoadReport2 function to specify which report you need. I'm sort of grasping just because I can't see your implementation.

Comment: @jwhaley58 I changed as you said, I got a new error, I put the Report name in the method LoadReport2 and NUll for history id as second parameter

Comment: What error is it giving you back now that you are trying to specify the report? Does that user that you are using to connect have appropriate permissions to execute the underlying query that the report is running?

Comment: @jwhaley58 You can see [here](http://ideone.com/2IShuO)

Comment: Where you have the name of the report, it looks like you have a subdirectory called testfolder? if that is still the case, you would need your report name to be "/TestFolder/testClaimHdr".

Comment: I added the /TestFolder/testClaimHdr, and dont get the error, I'm goint to add the render method :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49684/discussion-between-emilio-gort-and-jwhaley58)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some gochas that I only found through trial and error are some configuration issues, on the server that is running the reporting server service, make sure that in your file rsreportserver.config has been modified to allow for basic authentication. By default, if I'm understanding it correctly, it wants a more trustworthy connection type, but the sdk needs you to allow simple name and passwords to be passed. This means that  needs to be added to your authentication methods in the configuration.

so for example,

In
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.1\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config (Different for server and version, but you get the idea.)

```
<Authentication>
    <AuthenticationTypes>
        <RSWindowsNTLM/>
        <RSWindowsBasic/> ##you need to add this one##
    </AuthenticationTypes>
    <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>Off</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>
</Authentication>
```

IIRC you will have to restart the service for this to take effect.

Also, if you are attempting to RenderAs, some of the template files used to pop the headers have space in them towards the bottom that will prevent you from rendering as Excel, PDF, ect unless that has been fixed since I worked on it.

I'm looking through the code you provided, I may be reading it wrong, but it looks like you are trying to explicitly define the report you're after in the execution url. If that is in fact what you are doing, I believe the fix would be to only define the report base you are connecting to so for your example the url should be `http://172.16.4.63/ReportServer/`. After that connection is made, you would use the LoadReport2 function to specify which report you need.

Lastly, Where you have the name of the report, it looks like you have a subdirectory called testfolder? if that is still the case, you would need your report name to be "/TestFolder/testClaimHdr" in the call to LoadReport2.

Hope any of that helps.